# Python - Post File to Django With Extra Data

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to have my django rest framework app accept file uploads. The uploads should be accompanied by additional data that is descriptive of the file and is necessary for post-processing. Uploading the file seems to work fine, however, I can't seem to get the django app to access the other data. For example, I have the file `more_info.html` which I am trying to upload to my app:

```
import requests

url = "http://www.example.com/fileupload"
files = {'file':open('more_info.html','rb')
data = {'brand':'my brand','type':'html','level':'dev'}
headers = {'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data', 'Content-Disposition': 'attachment; filename="more_info.html"'}
r = requests.post(url,files=files,data=,headers=headers)
```

In my Django view I am trying to view my POST data with the following:

```
def post(self, request):
    print(request.POST)
    print(request.FILEs)
```

Both print statements are returning:

```
{u'file': <InMemoryUploadedFile: more_info.html (multipart/form-data)>}
```

How can I access the rest of the data in the request POST?

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
r = requests.post(url,files=files,data=,headers=headers)
```

You seem to be missing assigning data to data=.